# SQL Query: Count "id" occurrences in two tables

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have these 3 tables and I am trying to count, how many "hints" and "quizzes" are there for specific town id.

**db_town**

| id | town |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New York |

**db_hint**

| id | town_id | hint |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | test |

**db_quiz**

| id | town_id | quiz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | quiz 1 |
| 2 | 1 | quiz 2 |

I am using this statement, but it does not work :(

```
SELECT count(q.id),count(h.id) FROM `db_town` t LEFT JOIN `db_quiz` q ON t.id = q.town_id LEFT JOIN `db_hint` h ON t.id = h.town_id WHERE t.id = 1 GROUP BY t.id
```

and it produces this result:

| count(q.id) | count(h.id) |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |

Do I need to use two statements? Or is it possible to query it in a single SQL statement? I am using MariaDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select town_id, sum(is_hint), sum(is_quiz)
from ((select town_id, 1 as is_hint, 0 as is_quiz
       from hints
      ) union all
      (select town_id, 0, 1
       from quizzes
      )
     ) t
group by town_id;
```

Alternatively, you can use correlated subqueries:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from hints h where h.town_id = t.id),
       (select count(*) from quizzes q where q.town_id = t.id)
from towns t;
```

Two things to look out for:

- `JOIN`s are likely to multiply rows and throw off the counts.
- Getting `0` values if a town has no hints or quizzes.

Comment: It may be useful to add `towns` with two zeroes to `union all` for complete information about all the towns (with or without hints or quizzes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT (DISTINCT)` if both the hint id and the quiz id are unique.

```
SELECT
  count(distinct q.id),count(distinct h.id)
FROM `db_town` t
 LEFT JOIN `db_quiz` q ON t.id = q.town_id
 LEFT JOIN `db_hint` h ON t.id = h.town_id
WHERE t.id = 1 GROUP BY t.id
```